# Android Studio ! How to add Facebook-SDK in Libgdx Project?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, libgdx, facebook-android-sdk, android-studio-2.3

I tried to add facebook-android-sdk by file -> import -> new -> module -> facebook-android-sdk-4.20 -> facebook. added successfully
 but error occured "core 1.0 depends on one or more android libraries but is a jar."

Created New libgdx project.

Then I added facebook-android-sdk gradle module from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk added successfully 
but error occured "Error:Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' for project ':facebook' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

So how to do this?
And do we need to add separate Facebook-SDKs and dependencies for all projects or Libgdx will do it automatically?

I'm using Android studio-2.3, build tools 25.0.2, compile sdk version API 25.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build.gradle in the dependency section of the android sub project:

```
compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0"
```

Alternatively you can have a look at or just use: https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook/ and see how it is done there.

Comment: thanks TomGrill, BTW in libgdx project, the min SDK version is 8 (default), so need to change it to min 15 or ++.

Comment: @TomGrill, I have added dependency to build.gradle file of the android sub project.But I got this error message : "Integration error : Facebook classic are already loaded from .jar,Remove unnecessary dex file"